# Cognito - Check validity of idToken

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I have a back-end API in Node.js that retrieves an Amazon Cognito ID Token from a query parameter. I would need to check whether this token is valid. Is there any way to check this by using the `aws-sdk` or `amazon-cognito-identity-js` SDK?

Comment: Looks like you can so far only validate the `access_token`s in real time using `/oauth2/userInfo` endpoint, which does not accept id_tokens. hrrrr

Answer (score 3):

AWS official library aws-jwt-verify.

```
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from "aws-jwt-verify";

const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
    userPoolId: "user-pool-id",
    tokenUse: "access",
    clientId: "client-id",
})

// If no error is thrown it is a valid token
await verifier.verify(JWT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for couple of days and I just found how to do that, here's a fully working function that does the validation for you all you need to provide is the userPoolId and the pool_region related to the cognito pool you previously created and then you can call this function where ever you want by sending the token as a parameter and you will get your result on console if the token is valid or not, here's how to implement it:

1. create a file called tokenValidation.js (for example)
2. paste this code into it:

```js
// Cognito data
   
const userPoolId = "###########"; // Cognito user pool id here    
const pool_region = '#########'; // Region where your cognito user pool is created

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
const request = require('request');


// Token verification function
const  ValidateToken = (token) => {
    console.log('Validating the token...')
    request({
        url: `https://cognito-idp.${pool_region}.amazonaws.com/${userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
        json: true
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('validation token..')
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            pems = {};
            var keys = body['keys'];
            for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                //Convert each key to PEM
                var key_id = keys[i].kid;
                var modulus = keys[i].n;
                var exponent = keys[i].e;
                var key_type = keys[i].kty;
                var jwk = { kty: key_type, n: modulus, e: exponent};
                var pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
                pems[key_id] = pem;
            }
            //validate the token
            var decodedJwt = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
            if (!decodedJwt) {
                console.log("Not a valid JWT token");
                return;
            }

            var kid = decodedJwt.header.kid;
            var pem = pems[kid];
            if (!pem) {
                console.log('Invalid token');
                return;
            }

            jwt.verify(token, pem, function(err, payload) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Invalid Token.");
                } else {
                    console.log("Valid Token.");
                    console.log(payload);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(error)
            console.log("Error! Unable to download JWKs");
        }
    });
}

// Exporting it to call it anywere you want
exports.ValidateToken = ValidateToken
```

3. import that whenever you need it like this: `const validateToken = require('./tokenValidation')`
4. and finally call it like this: `validateToken.ValidateToken(result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken())`

I know this is an old question but I really hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: this only checks if it's of valid format and signed properly, and if it's unexpired. but it does not check if the user since the issuance of this token had their privileges revoked.

Answer (score 1):

I maid the check in a lambda with node using the AWS lib https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt.

By default it checks AccessToken but you can modify it to validate IdToken.

replace :

```
if (claim.token_use !== 'access') {
  throw new Error('claim use is not access');
}
```

by

```
if (claim.token_use !== "id") {
  throw new Error("claim use is not id");
}
```

and

```
console.log(`claim confirmed for ${claim.username}`);
result = {userName: claim.username, clientId: claim.client_id, isValid: true};
```

by

```
console.log(`claim confirmed for ${claim["cognito:username"]}`);
result = {userName: claim["cognito:username"], clientId: claim.aud, isValid: true};
```

You can even add more custom attributes in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can check with [aws-sdk CognitoIdentityServiceProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property)

```
var params = {   AccessToken: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */ };
 cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
else     console.log(data);           // successful response });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cognito's ID Token contains an "exp" claim when decoded, which indicates the time after which an ID Token would not be valid. 
Quoting OpenID's official [documentation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Claims),

> Expiration time on or after which the ID Token MUST NOT be accepted
>   for processing. The processing of this parameter requires that the
>   current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in
>   the value.

To decode the JWT Token in JavaScript, you could refer to a library like [JsonWebToken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), that is provided by Auth0.

To use the library to decode an existing ID Token using the mentioned library, you could refer to the following code snippet:

```
// get the decoded payload ignoring signature, no secretOrPrivateKey needed
var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

// get the decoded payload and header
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
console.log(decoded.header);
console.log(decoded.payload)
```

Kindly note that the JWT Tokens generated by Cognito are OIDC compliant, and you could also refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) for more information on Cognito's tokens.

Comment: You do not want to ignore the signature when verifying tokens otherwise it is trivial for attackers to create fake tokens

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a library to decode and verify Cognito tokens: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt